# Linear model and neural net from scratch, very low predictions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-regression

I've been trying to make a simple linear model from scratch, the problem is whenever I try to predict I get relatively low numbers and all of my predictions are below 0.5.

At first, I thought it might be a problem with the dataset, but now I tried to make a different model, and all of my predictions are below 0.05.

Here is the first model I made for Heart Disease Framinghum on Kaggle (Here the predictions are below 0.3)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv(r'...\framingham.csv')

print(dataset['TenYearCHD'].value_counts())
dataset = dataset.dropna()
print(dataset['TenYearCHD'].value_counts())

for col in dataset.columns:
    if dataset[col].nunique() > 10:
        max_n = dataset[col].max()
        dataset[col] /= max_n


def one_hot_encoding(col):
    for uni in dataset[col].unique():
        dataset[f"{col}_{uni}"] = (dataset[col] == uni).astype(int)
    dataset.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)

one_hot_encoding("education")

y = dataset["TenYearCHD"].to_numpy()
dataset.drop("TenYearCHD", axis=1, inplace=True)
print(dataset)

w = np.random.rand(len(dataset.columns))-0.5
b = 0

print(np.max(w))

LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
EPOCHES = 15

def forward_pass(w, xz, b):
    #return w * x + b
    return np.dot(w, xz.T) + b

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))


x = dataset.to_numpy()

train_x, test_x = np.split(x, [int(0.80*len(x))])
train_y, test_y = np.split(y, [int(0.80*len(x))])


for epoch in range(EPOCHES):
    z = forward_pass(w, train_x, b)
    z = sigmoid(z)
    MSE = np.mean((z-train_y)**2)

    dw = np.dot(train_x.T, (z-train_y))
    db = np.mean((z-train_y))

    w -= LEARNING_RATE*dw
    b -= LEARNING_RATE*db

    print(f"Epoch: {epoch} MSE: {MSE}")

z = sigmoid(forward_pass(w, test_x, b))
MSE = np.mean((z-test_y)**2)
print(MSE)
print(w)
for x, y in zip(test_x, test_y):
    prediction = sigmoid(forward_pass(w, x, b))
    print(prediction, y)
```

Here if for the Titanic model "Linear model and neural net from scratch" which is also found on Kaggle (here the predictions below 0.05)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv(r"...\train.csv")
test = pd.read_csv(r"...\test.csv")

def dataset_orangize(dataset):
    dataset = dataset.drop(['Ticket', 'Name', 'PassengerId', 'Cabin'],axis=1)
    dataset.dropna(inplace=True)
    dataset = one_hot_encoder(dataset, 'Sex')
    dataset = one_hot_encoder(dataset, 'Pclass')
    dataset = one_hot_encoder(dataset, 'Embarked')
    dataset['Age'] /= np.max(dataset['Age'])
    dataset['Fare'] /= np.log(dataset['Fare']+1)
    dataset.dropna(inplace=True)
    return dataset

def splitter(dataset):
    labels = dataset['Survived']
    dataset.drop('Survived', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return dataset, labels

def one_hot_encoder(dataset, col_name):
    for uni in dataset[col_name].unique():
        dataset[col_name+'_'+str(uni)] = (dataset[col_name]==uni).astype(int)
    dataset.drop(col_name, axis=1, inplace=True)
    return dataset
train_x, train_y = splitter(dataset_orangize(train))
test = dataset_orangize(test)

LEARNING_RATE = 0.03
EPOCHES = 20

w = np.random.randn(len(train_x.columns))-0.5
b = 0

train_x = train_x.to_numpy()
train_y = train_y.to_numpy()

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))


for epoch in range(EPOCHES):
    z=np.dot(train_x, w.T)+b
    z = sigmoid(z)
    MSE = np.mean((z-train_y)**2)

    dw = np.mean(np.dot(train_x.T, z-train_y))
    db = np.mean(z-train_y)

    w -= dw*LEARNING_RATE
    b -= db*LEARNING_RATE

    print(f'MSE: {MSE}    EPOCHES: {epoch}')


z=np.dot(train_x, w)+b
z = sigmoid(z)

for x, y in zip(train_x, train_y):
    z = np.dot(x, w.T) + b
    z = sigmoid(z)
    print(z, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, I used MSE as a cost function for Logistic Regression which is not recommended.
I didn't test it yet but I think it might solve it.